# Find the volume of the solid using the shell method?

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the volume of the solid created when the area bounded by f(x), g(x), and the y-axis is rotated about the y-axis?

$f(x) = \sqrt{x}$

$g(x) = 2x - 1$

I attempted to solve this by doing the shell method.

Circumference = $2\pi x$
Height = f(x) - g(x) = $\sqrt{x} - 2x + 1$

The limits are 0 and 1, so

$\pi\int_0^1 2 x (\sqrt{x} - 2x + 1) dx = .467 \pi$

The answer, however, is $.267\pi$

I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: The answer $\frac{7}{15}\pi$ looks right.

Comment: I thought so too, but if you evaluate using the disk method and a dy integral, the answer is $\frac{4}{15}\pi$.

Comment: I did it another (easier) way, got $\frac{2}{3}\pi$ (from the volume  of the containing cone) minus $\frac{1}{5}\pi$, so again $\frac{7}{15}$.

Comment: How did you set it up? With a dx integral?

Comment: The second way, with integration with respect to $y$. We have an upside down cone from rotating $y=2x-1$, with height $2$ and base radius $1$, so volume $\frac{2}{3}\pi$. From this take away the "hole" obtained by rotating $x=y^2$. The hole has volume $\int_0^1 \pi (y^2)^2\,dy$.